# dismiss two controllers Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this situation :

I have a first view controller , when tap on button in it I open in modal mode another view controller , in this view controller when I tap another button I open in modal view another view controller and in it there is a button and when I tap on it I want to go to first view controller without re-initialize it. 
How do I do it?

Comment: Have the second view controller dismiss its presenter.

Comment: You can use completion blocks as well. When you will dismiss a view controller you will get completion block.

Answer (score 7):

This is the perfect situation for an *unwind segue*.

Put this in your first viewController (the one you want to return to):

```
@IBAction func backFromVC3(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("We are back in VC1!")
}
```

Then in the Storyboard in your 3rd viewController, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from your button to the exit icon at the top of the viewController and choose `backFromVC3` from the pop-up.

Now, when the user presses the button in VC3, both VC3 and VC2 will be dismissed and you will return to VC1.

---

If you are not using Storyboards, you can dismiss the viewControllers with code.  Here is code for a button's handler to dismiss two levels of viewController:

```
func doDismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Use presentingViewController twice to go back two levels and call
    // dismissViewController to dismiss both viewControllers.
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are your viewControllers in the Storyboard, or is all of your UI done with code?

Comment: I added a way to dismiss your viewControllers with code.

Comment: Worked like a charm for swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reply and edited my question :)

I found 2 line code to resolved my problem:

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil).

And that work well.

Thanks very much