# swift Dismiss multi uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

My app have **4** controllers :

```
A: [UINavigationController] UIViewController --> 

  B: [UINavigationController] UIViewController --> 

    C: [UINavigationController] UIViewController -->

      D: [UINavigationController] UIViewController -->
```

(all of them embed a navigation controller).

So, the structure on storyboard is :

**A** `UINavigationController` ---> show segue --> **B** `UINavigationController`--> show segue --> **C** `UINavigationController`--> show segue --> **D** `UINavigationController`

Now when I've completed one task flow and stay on `UIViewController` **D**.

I want to navigate to `UIViewController` **A** to start new task

(dismiss 3 navigation controller : **B**,**C**,**D**)

What can I do that ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, try to improve the readability of your post, and add some the relevant code.

Comment: First, you should only have 1 Navigation controller in your setup before A.  Then A->B, B->C, and C->D segues should be Show (Push).  Take a look at this answer on how to dismiss multiple viewControllers.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36984004/1630618

Comment: with appdelegate set root view controller to navigation(A)

Comment: @vacawama you dont know what his project must doing, so it can have also 1 navigator to 1 controller, depend by what kind of result him would reach.